# How do I create a tf.Tensor from a pandas DataFrame containing arrays?

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas DataFrame like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf  # Version 2.8.0
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": 
                   ["i123", "i456"],  
                   "col": [np.array(["igh", "ghdd", "yu"]),
                           np.array(["uh", "lkk", "nj"])]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id      col
0   i123    [igh, ghdd, yu]
1   i456    [uh, lkk, nj]
```

I would to create a `Tensor` from the values of the `col` column, in order to use them in a specific use case. I have tried converting the values like

```
values = df["col"].to_numpy()
values
```

Which looks like:

```
array([array(['igh', 'ghdd', 'yu'], dtype='<U4'),
       array(['uh', 'lkk', 'nj'], dtype='<U3')], dtype=object)
```

When I try to convert this to a Tensor, by

```
tf.constant(values)
```

I get an exception:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I can see from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) that the tf.constant method should work on a very similar array
[image: TF docs]

The `values` variable I create have `.shape` like `(2,)` while the image below have `(2, 3)`, which might be the problem.
I can't seem to get the dtype and/or shape to match exactly, and I'm unsure how to get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf  # Version 2.8.0
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": 
                   ["i123", "i456"],  
                   "col": [np.array(["igh", "ghdd", "yu"]),
                           np.array(["uh", "lkk", "nj"])]})

values = df["col"].to_list()
print(tf.constant(values))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[b'igh' b'ghdd' b'yu']
 [b'uh' b'lkk' b'nj']], shape=(2, 3), dtype=string)
```

Or

```
values = np.stack(df["col"].to_numpy())
print(tf.constant(values))
```